# Excelsior Luminis - Making sure this translation is accurate

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, latin-to-english-translation

Higher than light is what we are trying to get across basically just trying to make sure we say and spell it in a way that makes sense for a motto/ description motto

Comment: What does 'higher than light' even mean? What's the context? It's hard to tell whether you're saying it correctly when the English itself doesn't make very much obvious sense.

Answer (score 4):

The spelling is fine, but the grammar not quite ;-)

The problem is that *luminis* is the genetive (“of light”), and you want the ablative *lumine* to say “than light.” It's a special use of the ablative called the *ablativus comparationis* (a.k.a. ablative of comparison), and it very, very, *very* typically comes before the adjective, so you should say:

**Lumine excelsior**

You may find it interesting that a common Latin expression is [*solis*] *luce clarior* (or *clarius*), meaning something like “clear as day” (literally “brighter than sunlight”).